# Can't create Release notifications in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, notifications, release

We passed from TFS 2015 to TFS 2017.2 last week. Apparently, we don't have the Release option when setting notifications. Do you know why is that? Or how can we enable the Release notifications?

[Current Notifications Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71vka.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Release notifications are **only available with TFS 2018 later** and VSTS. It's not able to use it in TFS2017. You could refer below blog:

> *We are now announcing the feature as generally available on all accounts and be the only available release notification settings
>   experience. The same experience is also available with TFS 2018.*
>
> **[Managing Release Notifications](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/04/managing-release-notifications/)**

As a workaround, you could use some 3rd-party E-mail extensions to notify peoples in the Release definition such as [*Send Email*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dutchworkz.SendEmail).

You could also set up your own E-mail extension, just follow this blog as a tutorial: [Sending Email Notification from VSTS/TFS Build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalmrangers/2016/12/19/sending-email-notification-from-vststfs-build/)